# Dynamic element not receiving click event in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I posted a question earlier but realized I left quite a few important details out.  I am essentially using a Javascript framework that adds content to the page dynamically.  Two elements that are dynamically added are:

```
<li class="l-item facebook">
    <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"/></svg>
</li>

<li class="l-item twitter">
    <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"/></svg>
</li>
```

To handle click events on these I am using `.on` as I believe this uses delegation.  At the moment I have something like this:

```
jq('body').on('click', '.twitter, .facebook', function() {
    alert("CLICKED");
});
```

Now this works perfectly nearly everywhere apart from IE.  In IE there is a strange issue. The Twitter icon is triggered fine, the popup displays.  However, the Facebook icon does not.  Why would one work and not the other?  This is the same if I put both in their own functions.

Any advice appreciated.  No errors/warnings are displayed and I have tried researching without success.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tested this in IE11 and it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/fpk3hn37/ so I guess it must be something else causing this

Comment: That works for me as well.  I am thinking it has something to do with it being added dynamically, after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Could be, for us to help and to check that, we need a working code snippet reproducing it ... btw, have you tried without the SVG, using a simple text?

Comment: Actually quite difficult to reproduce because the frontend was created and compiled by someone else and I am just applying some click events

Comment: So it becomes very difficult for us .... have you tried adding the on click 2 times, one with each selector? ... What if you swap selector order, `'.facebook, .twitter'`, does then facebook work but not twitter?

Comment: I have tried that.  I have noticed the the `<use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"/>` takes up only a few pixels on the svg, and if clicked this works in IE.  Strange how it is like this for the Facebook icon but not the Twitter icon.

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: Possibly.  Will do some further testing, thanks

Comment: If, then vote to close as "Off topic, ... an issue that can't be reproduced"